# How do I create a backup of my PS3?

Tags: ps3

I've got two ps3 and, on the second one, I've tried to sign in with my account to download a game (GTA5) but I couldn't find it in the downloaded content section. So I thought that I may try to do a full backup of my first PS3, but I don't know how to copy the game. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Did you buy GTA5 digitally?  Or do you have the disc?

Comment: No, I'va downloaded it from the PS Store

Comment: So digital..  

And why copy the game when you do a backup? Just backup the save data and re-download on the actual game when you need it.

Comment: How do I re-download it? If I go to the Playstation Store and then in the downloaded content section, I can't find it! The game isn't there.